# How to combine embedded ruby with a ternary operator in a view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, embedded-ruby

Currently I have in my view something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <% if item.status == nil %>
       <td><%= image_tag "/assets/nil.gif" %></td>
   <% else %>
       <% if item.status == "1" %>
           <td><%= image_tag "/assets/yes.gif" %></td>
       <% else %>
           <td><%= image_tag "/assets/no.gif" %></td>
       <% end %>
   <% end %>
</tr>
...
```

Can I use a ternary operator here? I didn't know where to put the ? or the : when using this combination of embedded ruby and html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= 1 == 1 ? "one is one" : "one is two" %>
# outputs "one is one"
```

Therefore:

```
<%= image_tag "/assests/#{ item.status == "1" ? "yes" : "no"}.gif" %>
```

However, in this case, since you are testing three possible values in all, a `switch` statement inside a helper method might be best.

```
# app/helpers/items_help.rb

def gif_name(status)
  case status
  when nil
    "nil"
  when "1"
    "yes"
  else
    "no"
  end
end

# app/views/items/action.html.erb

<td><%= image_tag "/assests/#{gif_name(item.status)}.gif" %></td>
```

Comment: I think he means including the item.status == nil and item.status == 1

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
<%= item.status.nil? ? <td><%= image_tag "/assets/nil.gif" %></td> : <td><%= image_tag "/assets/#{item.status == '1' ? 'yes.gif' : 'no.gif'" %></td>
```

or

```
<%= item.status.nil? ? <td><%= image_tag "/assets/nil.gif" %></td> : item.status == "1" ? <td><%= image_tag "/assets/yes.gif" %></td> : <td><%= image_tag "/assets/no.gif" %></td> %>
```

The ternary operator substitutes the if statement by having the `condition ? condition_true : condition_false`

Comment: I am trying the second option you listed. This isn't working for me. I think something is off with the placement of the <% %>. I thought that maybe there was supposed to be a %> right before the first <td> but that didn't work. Trying to figure it out...

Comment: I forgot to add the %> at the end of the entire thing. What Charles Caldwell said is right though. You should not try to stick that much logic in your views. It gets messy. Make helper methods instead.